# Mongo: Does the number of fields in a document affect the query performance?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, spring-mvc

I have a collection called school and the document in it is like:

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "_class" : "com.aixueniao.server.model.School",
    "companyUserId" : 0,
    "schoolUserId" : 0,
    "schoolName" : "校区名称",
    "showSchoolName" : 0,
    "gradeIds" : "[]",
    "firstLevelSubjectIds" : "[]",
    "secondLevelSubjectIds" : "[]",
    "classType" : "",
    "introduction" : "校区介绍",
    "mainImageId" : 0,
    "imageIds" : "[]",
    "longitude" : 0.0,
    "latitude" : 0.0,
    "locationId" : 0,
    "address" : "校区地址",
    "runningTime" : 0.0,
    "teacherCount" : 0,
    "telephone" : "",
    "fixedPhone" : "",
    "createTime" : "2017-01-13 01:16:54",
    "expirationTime" : "2017-01-13 01:16:54",
    "schoolStatus" : "ARREARS",
    "authorizationStatus" : "NO",
    "rejectReason" : "无"
}
```

There are about 26 fields in the document, does the number of fields affect the query performance? I will query on 4 fields and will use $near query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is yes, which is why Mongo provides us with features like [projections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/#use-projections-to-return-only-necessary-data) to achieve better performance by not having the database return all the fields in the document